# Quarantine message upon compiling in Dev C++

Tags: c++, runtime-error, memory-error, dc++

I have newly setup Dev c++ in my laptop in excitement of ditching Turbo C++ for this more intermediate IDE to use for practice purposes...

I'm quite new to this IDE and just went off exploring about it with it's instruction manual and even online.

I could manage to set it up to the point where and when it looked battle ready and tried the customary "Hello World"

But upon compiling, I got no output upon the trial run. Instead, I saw a pop up from good ol' McAfee that there is a threat to be quarantined... I have confirmed that the executable file that was created has caused that pop up to occur the many times that it did (given that I spammed the compile option in the toolbar)

Any solution to make that a non threat?

Comment: Check if there is an option to exclude a folder from automated scans.

Comment: I've removed the software recommendation request as that would make it off-topic for Superuser. Let's just handle the issue of McAfee munching your hard work.

Comment: Oh... I'm new to Stack Exchange's sites. I just thought it'd be useful to put it up here since it was put off topic even in Stack Overflow. But thanks anyhoo. • So I've tried that file exclusion before and have even changed the directories to my desktop. And obviously have had no luck with that